# Find $U\cap V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find $U\cap V$.

Given $$U = \text{span}{(1,1,-1),(2,3,-1),(3,1,-5)}$$
$$ V=\text{span} {(1,1,-3),(3,-2,-8),(2,1,-3)}$$

$A. U$

$B. V$

$C. \{0\}$

$D.$ None of the above

**ATTEMPT**:
I have found that the dimension of $U\cap V$ is $2$. So anwer maybe A or D.

But how do i check which one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if we form a matrix whose three rows are the vectors that span $V$ and row reduce, then we get the identity matrix. Thus, $V = \mathbb R^3$. But since $\dim U = 2$ and $U \cap \mathbb R^3 = U \subsetneq \mathbb R^3 = V$, we conclude that $U \cap V = U$.

Comment: can you justify your first line a bit more please. thanks

Comment: How did you figure out that $\dim(U \cap V) = 2$? Did you compute $\dim V$?

Comment: i computed dim U , dim V ,dim U+V and used dimension formula

Comment: So how did you compute $\dim V$? It equals $3$, which is equivalent to saying that $V = \mathbb R^3$ (since $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$, which has dimension $3$).

Comment: I checked no of free variables  by making it echelon form